# incorrect use of ruby's sort_by function

Tags: ruby, sorting, arrays

My sort function is clearly not working, I am trying to sort `ALL_VIEWS` by `@permalink.length`:

```
ALL_VIEWS.sort_by {|view| view.permalink.length}

ALL_VIEWS[0..4].each do |view|
    puts view.inspect
    puts view.permalink.length
end
```

this produces:

```
#<View:0x1014da7b8 @permalink="xxxx">
4
#<View:0x1014da790 @permalink="yyyyy">
5
#<View:0x1014da718 @permalink="zzz">
3
#<View:0x1014da6a0 @permalink="aaaaaaa">
7
#<View:0x1014da628 @permalink="b">
1
```

I am expecting the following result:

```
#<View:0x1014da628 @permalink="b">
1
#<View:0x1014da718 @permalink="zzz">
3
#<View:0x1014da7b8 @permalink="xxxx">
4
#<View:0x1014da790 @permalink="yyyyy">
5
#<View:0x1014da6a0 @permalink="aaaaaaa">
7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
ALL_VIEWS.replace ALL_VIEWS.sort_by {|view| view.permalink.length }
```

for the first line. `sort_by` does not sort in place - it returns the sorted array and does not modify the original one.

Comment: Even better, use the mutating version `sort_by!`, available in 1.9.2 or by requiring `backports`

Comment: @Marc: Yeah, while I was answering this question, I looked at the documentation for that method and was surprised when it wasn't there. Now I realize that I was looking at the 1.8 docs.

Comment: I can't find the documentation for sort_by!, can someone link me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### The Problem

`sort_by` does not mutate the object, it is a method of Enumerable that returns an Array whose elements are the elements yielded by your object's `each` method. It then sorts *that array* by the criteria given in your block. But notice that it does not sort *your array* [docs for Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120)

You could normally do what Adrian suggested, and assign the results back to the original variable, but your original is a constant, which is going to give you issues.

### The Solution(s)

So you need to either make `ALL_VIEWS` something other than a constant (if you are wanting to change it, then it really shouldn't be a constant anyway). Perhaps a class variable?

---

Or you need to have these values sorted before they are assigned to `ALL_VIEWS`

```
ALL_VIEWS = view_paths.map do |path| 
  View.new 'views/pages' , path 
end.sort_by do |view| 
  view.permalink.length
end
```

---

Or you can sort in place with something other than the `sort_by` method

```
ALL_VIEWS.sort! do |view1,view2| 
  view1.permalink.length <=> view2.permalink.length
end
```

This will work, but again, if you are doing stuff like this, then should ALL_VIEWS really be a constant? [docs for Array#sort and Array#sort!](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002185)

Comment: Awesome. ALL_VIEWS should be a constant so it should be sorted before it is assigned - your first code snippet is just the ticket. Thanks, this is a great answer +1.